# reverse order of children span for a class using JSX in .mdx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am using a .mdx and I want to write a JSX function in .mdx to reverse the order of spans with class="base" inside class="katex-html"

consider below html and I want to change the order

```
<span class="katex-html" aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="base">
        1
    </span>
    <span class="base">
        2
    </span>
</span>
```

final result should be:

```
<span class="katex-html" aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="base">
        2
    </span>
    <span class="base">
        1
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Ref : here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70192086/possible-to-render-components-in-reverse-manner-in-jsx Might be a duplicate question